# app.config.from_object(__name__)は何をしているのか

Tags: python, flask

チュートリアル通りにアプリケーションを作っています。
http://study-flask.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/02.html
の通りにチュートリアルを進めている中で、

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
     abort, render_template, flash
from contextlib import closing

DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
```

というコードが出てきました。この、

```
 app.config.from_object(__name__)
```

がどういう役割なのかわかりません。チュートリアルには、大文字の変数を集めてくるもの、と書かれていましたが、集めてきてどうするのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

そのモジュールに書いた大文字の変数群

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'
```

を一体何のつもりで書きましたか?
Flaskアプリケーションの環境設定だと思って書いたのではないですか?

その行は「このモジュールがFlaskアプリケーションの環境設定用のオブジェクトになっているからこのモジュールから(大文字だけの変数を)環境設定として読み込んでね」という役割です。

---

> The configuration files themselves are actual Python files. Only
>   values in uppercase are actually stored in the config object later on.
>   So make sure to use uppercase letters for your config keys.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#configuring-from-files